# change id in csv file 'a' and change all occurence of old csv file 'a' id in csv file 'b' column to the new id

Tags: sql, excel, csv, google-sheets, replace

I have two large csv files, using sql, terminal, sheets or any online resource, I'm trying to update the id in csv file(a) then find the old id in csv file(b) and update it to the new id.

#### CSV_FILE_A

```
ID name description <br/>
1 john xxxx<br/>
2 jack yyyy<br/>
3 jane zzzz
```

#### CSV_FILE_B

```
B_ID TYPE A_ID<br/>
5 Table   2<br/>
6 Chair   3<br/>
7 Pen   2<br/>
```

In this instance i want to replace the id's in CSV_FILE_A with a new id and then find the old occurrence in CSV_FILE_B column 'A_ID' and update it to the new ID from CSV_FILE_A.
So, if i change '3 jane zzzz' to 30 jane zzzz' in CSV_FILE_A.
'6 Chair 3'  would change to '6 Chair 30' in CSV_FILE_B.

Answer (score 0):

According to me this can be done in excel and use = operator when you want a matching condition

like cell A3 = C3

Comment: Wouldn't that need both files to be in the same sheet? and also some id's from csv(a) are repeated in csv(b), (1 to many) so a direct substitution of cells couldn't do the trick.